# Suspension of magnet with a thread

Tags: magnetic-fields, solar-system, magnetostatics

Recently, I have read about magnetic poles of Jupiter. Peculiar thing is, that Jupiter has 3 magnetic poles.

If you would suspend a magnet via thread on earth, it would align itself in geographic north-south direction. If we would repeat the same thing on planet Jupiter, what would be the result.

Comment: Please link to the source claiming three poles. That is not consistent with Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere_of_Jupiter

Answer (score 0):

A magnet is subject to a torque which tends to align it with any external magnetic field.  Freely mounted near the earth, it aligns itself with the horizontal component of the earth's field which goes south to north, and it also dips due to the vertical component (which comes up in the far south and goes down in the northern hemisphere). If Jupiter has three poles, two of them would have the same polarity and a magnet would align with the resultant field at its location. (The total magnetic flux associated with the two similar poles should be the same as that with the odd one.)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the claim that Jupiter has more than two poles at face value, you haven't given enough information to say what will happen.

A suspended magnet doesn't point in the direction of magnetic North on Earth; it points in whatever direction the local magnetic field is pointing. If you don't have any magnets around you, so your local magnetic field is dominated by the ambient magnetic field on Earth, then the needle will point in the direction of the ambient magnetic field, which points toward magnetic North. But if you have a strong magnet nearby, you can make the needle point in any direction you want by moving that magnet. The point is, there's nothing special about "magnetic North", other than the fact that the ambient field points in that direction.

Therefore, on Jupiter, your question boils down to: in what direction does the ambient magnetic field point? The answer is simple for a magnetic dipole, which essentially only has one vector parameter (the direction of the dipole moment). For a more complicated arrangement with multiple poles, the answer will depend on the parameters of that more complicated arrangement. You have to actually calculate what the ambient magnetic field profile is, and it will depend in a non-trivial way on the way the poles are oriented.

For what it is worth, I find it very hard to imagine a planet generating a magnetic field that isn't a dipole to a first approximation. A planet is essentially a spinning top, and if it has iron or ionized material, then the spinning iron / current due to the spinning ionized matter will generate a dipole field.